# How to call a Java Spring utility jar from a Java Spring consumer application

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am new to Spring and I have tried Googling this, but I am not finding any practical guidance.

I have a Maven Spring utility application that has its own Spring configuration.xml.

I would like other consuming applications (also Maven and Spring most likely) to call this utility by including it in their classpath, and with a minimimum of adjustment, just have the utility application work.

In summary, I would like to have a jar containing my utility code and Spring xml files, then place that jar in the classpath of a consumer application with a minimum of adjustment to the consumer's spring config or command line, and have the utility just work in the consumer application context.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: should be simple enough to publish your jar as a maven artefact into a repository and then include the artefact descriptor in the poms of projects that need to use it

Comment: [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/)?

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you're describing is what Maven was made for. You can simply make the utility module a stand-alone Maven module (with its own pom.xml) that will produce a jar artifact (which is the default type). This jar should and will contain all the Spring configs as well. Later on, when ever you need it, you just declare a dependency to the utility artifact and Maven will make sure it ends up on the classpath so you can use its features.